# Why does Cura create this turquoise support structure?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I am just using Cura for the first time.

This is what my model looks like in Fusion 360:
[image]

Here is a close-up look:

[image]

And this is what Cura creates for me.

I assume the turquoise area is a support structure.
Why does it do that?

Also, I don't understand why it marks the edges as red. I assume this means that there is problem.

Thank you!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each color has a special meaning:

- turquoise: Support (in your case **Build Plate Adhesion**)
- Red: Shell
- Green: Inner Wall
- Yellow: Top / Bottom

And so on ; you can see them if you click on **"Color Scheme: Line Type"** on the **Preview Interface**, and select what you want to see.

The **turquoise** is your support for bed adhesion (see the **Build Plate adhesion** tree on your **Print Settings** interface), the **red** one is your **shell**.

Nothing is wrong, please read the doc, it could be useful sometimes ...